# IAM user policy that can only triggered by a AWS service (Condition)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I was wondering if it was possible to have a IAM user that can have a policy that can only be triggered by a certain AWS service.

I know it is possible to restrict the policy to be triggered by a certain IP with the following:

`"Condition": { "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "123.45.167.89"} }`

Is there a condition for an aws service? (e.g. sts.amazonaws.com)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/createdomain-configure-slow-logs.html) for policy that allows to write `CloudWatch` logs to `OpenSearch` (`es.amazonaws.com`) service:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "es.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "logs:PutLogEvents",
        "logs:PutLogEventsBatch",
        "logs:CreateLogStream"
      ],
      "Resource": "cw_log_group_arn:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see it is possible to set [`Principal`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) to grant access for specific resource:

```json
"Principal": {"Service": "es.amazonaws.com"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately Principal only works for trusted policy on IAM role. It doesn't look like it works on IAM user.

Comment: @IAmRobot I can't figure out how it should work for user? Policy triggered by user is triggered by user not by service. Policy that only be able triggered by specific service but triggering by user will every time fail. user != service in any cases (unless user is not a Robot). Creating of restricted user (using permissions) that able access only `X` service is a logically most correct way.

Comment: hey mate, so I inherited an AWS account that has an app that use an IAM user to gets a federated session token to upload to a s3 bucket. So that IAM user has read/write access to a s3 bucket so it can be passed on to the federated user.

When looking at the cloudtrail logs on this AWS key, i can see that the eventSource is always used by "sts.amazonaws.com". Ideally, to protect that key, I would like to block any access that doesn't come from "sts.amazonaws.com". So if that key gets leaked, it can't be used. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @IAmRobot It is possible to set separated policy for S3 Bucket (see [Granting permissions for Amazon S3 Inventory and Amazon S3 analytics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html)), and it support `Principal`

Comment: cheers man, yeah I'll probably need to set the access at the bucket level